# Running a linear regression model with fitted values on columns which contain specific names

Tags: r

I have the following data:

df1:

```
   Retiro Escuelas_Aguirre Av_Ramon_y_Cajal
1      13               29               26
2      31               42               55
3      44               51               73
4      50               52               65
5      36               46               59
6      22               34               39
7      30               39               40
8      22               31               49
9      21               39               47
10     37               41               56
```

df2:

```
# A tibble: 10 × 4
   `Escuelas_Aguirre vs Av_Ramon_y_Cajal` `Escuelas_Aguirre vs Retiro` `Av_Ramon_y_Cajal v… `Arturo_Soria vs C_…
                                    <dbl>                        <dbl>                <dbl>                <dbl>
 1                                   22.1                         13.2                 17.9                 26.7
 2                                   34.0                         22.3                 37.6                 45.6
 3                                   42.2                         28.6                 49.9                 52.5
 4                                   43.1                         29.3                 44.4                 51.7
 5                                   37.6                         25.1                 40.3                 46.5
 6                                   26.7                         16.7                 26.7                 37.0
 7                                   31.3                         20.2                 27.4                 27.5
 8                                   23.9                         14.6                 33.5                 24.9
 9                                   31.3                         20.2                 32.2                 33.6
10                                   33.1                         21.6                 38.3                 46.5
```

I want to run a regression like the following:

```
lm(df1$Retiro ~ df2$`Escuelas_Aguirre vs Retiro`)
lm(df1$Retiro ~ df2$`Av_Ramon_y_Cajal vs Retiro`)
```

So it takes the `Retiro` from `df1` and regresses it on the fitted values for `Retiro` in `df2` for the columns which contain the name `Reitro` (ignoring the two other columns in `df2`).

My question is, how can I generalise this so I can obtain the regression results in a similar way for all 3 columns in `df1` where there name appears in the column names in `df2`.

i.e.

```
df1$Escuelas_Aguirre ~ df2$`Escuelas_Aguirre vs Av_Ramon_y_Cajal`
df1$Escuelas_Aguirre ~ df2$`Escuelas_Aguirre vs Retiro`
df1$Av_Ramon_y_Cajal ~ df2$`Av_Ramon_y_Cajal vs Retiro`
```

I tried to use `gsub` / `contains()` to filter the `df2` down into separate dataframes, one for each name in `df1` but I think there is a better way to perform the linear regression model.

Data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(Retiro = c(13, 31, 44, 50, 36, 22, 30, 22, 21, 
37), Escuelas_Aguirre = c(29, 42, 51, 52, 46, 34, 39, 31, 39, 
41), Av_Ramon_y_Cajal = c(26, 55, 73, 65, 59, 39, 40, 49, 47, 
56)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(`Escuelas_Aguirre vs Av_Ramon_y_Cajal` = c(`1` = 22.123759378087, 
`2` = 33.9922357048987, `3` = 42.2088731618608, `4` = 43.1218328793022, 
`5` = 37.644074574654, `6` = 26.6885579653575, `7` = 31.2533565525643, 
`8` = 23.9496788130334, `9` = 31.2533565525643, `10` = 33.0792759874471
), `Escuelas_Aguirre vs Retiro` = c(`1` = 13.1525669184539, `2` = 22.301605800299, 
`3` = 28.6355557953872, `4` = 29.3393280170644, `5` = 25.1166946870015, 
`6` = 16.6714280268757, `7` = 20.1902891352614, `8` = 14.5601113618442, 
`9` = 20.1902891352614, `10` = 21.5978335786157), `Av_Ramon_y_Cajal vs Retiro` = c(`1` = 17.8766296715372, 
`2` = 37.6130164990209, `3` = 49.8631876333299, `4` = 44.418667129193, 
`5` = 40.3352767510903, `6` = 26.723975490748, `7` = 27.4045405537651, 
`8` = 33.5296261209192, `9` = 32.1684959948849, `10` = 38.293581562039
), `Arturo_Soria vs C_Farolillo` = c(`1` = 26.6522937775047, 
`2` = 45.6382158633481, `3` = 52.5421875309455, `4` = 51.6791910724967, 
`5` = 46.5012123218041, `6` = 37.0082512788677, `7` = 27.5152902359313, 
`8` = 24.926300860585, `9` = 33.5562654450726, `10` = 46.5012123218041
)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Answer (score 1):

Behind the scenes, this will forcibly copy all these columns from different DFs into a matrix object, so there's no performance bonus from calling them like that. You can avoid the problem by creating a new data.frame object with the columns you want and passing that instead:

```
new_df = data.frame(y=df1$Retiro, x1=df2$...)
```

And then calling `lm` on that.